# How to store values from TextView so that they don't get cleared when leaving activity?

Tags: android, save

I have an issue with my app where if I navigate to the about activity while I'm in the result activity,the TextView values are cleared.I have tried so far by setting the about activity to `finish()` when I navigate back to result activity but that didn't work.I'm wondering if there is a way to store the values so they don't get wiped when I navigate away? I have shown in screenshots below what I'm talking about.

[image: Calculation results]
[image: Navigate to about activity and select back to go back to result activity]

[image: Values cleared when I navigate back]

Comment: u can use shared pref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do so (meing mark# string variables or arrMark an array of strings):

```
@Override
protected final void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState)
{
    // Save variables.
    outState.putString("mark1", mark1);
    outState.putString("mark2", mark2);
    outState.putString("mark3", mark3);
    // ...
    // or better, if you have your values in a string array:
    outState.putStringArray("marks", arrMarks);
}

@Override
protected final void onRestoreInstanceState(final Bundle outState)
{
    // Restore saved variables and reshow activities if they were open.
    mark1 = outState.getString("mark1", "");
    mark2 = outState.getString("mark2", "");
    mark3 = outState.getString("mark3", "");
    // ...
    // or better, if you have your values in a string array:
    arrMarks = outState.getStringArray("marks");
}
```

Comment: Just seen this now,I implemented the above outside of `OnCreate()` but I'm getting errors with the variables like ` - mark1 cannot be resolved to a variable and `- The method getBoolean(String, boolean) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments 
  (String, String)`
`

Comment: Sorry! I edited my answer... it's not getBoolean, it's **getString**! my typos... ;) We're dealing with strings - If we were dealing with Booleans, **outState.getBoolean("markXYZ", false);**

Comment: I tried this edited version and I'm still getting the following errors: cannot convert from String to double on restoreInstanceState and The method putString(String, String) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, double) on savedInstanceState

Comment: Of course. You're getting type mismatch. So, if you work with strings, use putString/getString. If you work with double, use putDouble/getDouble. If you're using mixed types, you have to do explicit type conversions.

Comment: I implemented these methods now,but the values are still cleared when I go back to the activity.Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I assume you are **not** using both the "putXYZ" and the "putXYZArray" methods at the same time, are you? Because these are two ALTERNATIVE ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: No I'm not using the both..I'm guessing there's an extra step to doing this.

Comment: I suppose you declared your mark# as strings in the declaration section. I also suppose (I see no code, nor layout) you have some TextViews called (maybe) txtMark#. Now, these must be valorized by using a syntax like **txtMark#.setText(mark#);**. You can do that after retrieving the mark# values in onRestoreInstanceState.

Answer (score 2):

Just save this into Temporary preferences. then retrieve whenever you want

**To save**

```
SharedPreference preferenece = getSharedPreference("File Name", MODE_PRIVATE);
preference.edit().putString("Mark1").commit();
```

**To Retrieve**

SharedPreference preferenece = getSharedPreference("Pref File Name", MODE_PRIVATE);
   String mark1 = preference.getString("Mark1");

then pass it back to TextView or whatever